# How to get multi-stage .env to work in serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless, dotenv

In a nodejs app, I am having .env files with multiple stages. which is `.env-dev`, `.env-stage` and `.env-prod`.

how to make the variables available in the deployment using `sls deploy --<STAGE>`?
please provide examples both the `.env` and the `serverless.yml`.